# Angular life-cycle events call without implementing interface?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working with angular application and I found that angular life cycle events is call without implement interface.In below example if i remove interface from component then all the angular life-cycle hooks is working fine. **My question about without implement interface why angular is call all the events?**

I know in typescript we can use all OOP concepts that we can use with c#.

life-cycle.component.ts

```
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  OnChanges,
  SimpleChanges,
  Input,
  AfterViewInit,
  DoCheck,
  AfterViewChecked,
  AfterContentChecked,
  AfterContentInit,
  OnDestroy
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-life-cycle',
  templateUrl: './life-cycle.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./life-cycle.component.css']
})
export class LifeCycleComponent
  implements
    OnChanges,
    OnInit,
    DoCheck,
    AfterViewInit,
    AfterViewChecked,
    AfterContentChecked,
    AfterContentInit,
    OnDestroy {
  @Input('appTitle') appTitle: string;
  constructor() {
    console.log('constructor called!');
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    console.log('ngOnChanges called!');
    console.log(changes);
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('ngOnInit called!');
  }

  ngDoCheck() {
    console.log('ngDoCheck called!');
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log('ngAfterViewInit called!');
  }
  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    console.log('ngAfterViewChecked called!');
  }
  ngAfterContentInit() {
    console.log('ngAfterContentInit called!');
  }
  ngAfterContentChecked() {
    console.log('ngAfterContentChecked called!');
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    //console.log('ngOnDestroy called!');
  }
}
```

life-cycle.component.html

```
<p>
  life-cycle works!
</p>
```

Comment: who is downvoted my question? Provide comment with downvote.

Comment: The interfaces are optional.
It's good practice to add interfaces to TypeScript directive classes in order to benefit from strong typing and editor tooling.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The use of the Angular lifecycle interfaces is optional.
They just help you as a developer.

Technically, TypeScript is compiled to JavaScript, which doesn't have interfaces.
Angular just calls the JavaScript Lifecycle methods if they exist.
That's the reason why it doesn't make any difference if you use the interfaces or not. (Source: [Docs](https://v8.angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#interfaces-are-optional-technically))

Nevertheless, you should use the interfaces for multiple reasons: (Credits to @Nick)

1. It is more clear which Lifecycle events are actually used. In big classes with many methods you quickly lose the overview. The use of the interfaces allow you to quickly determine all used Lifecycle methods in one place - at the beginning of the TypeScript Class.
2. The TypeScript compiler warns you if you don't implement the Lifecycle methods correctly, for example if you forgot to implement the method, misspelled the method name or the method was accidentally removed.
3. Angular recommends this in their [styleguide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-09-01).

In case you are using [`@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin`](https://github.com/angular-eslint/angular-eslint), you can enable the [`@angular-eslint/use-lifecycle-interface`](https://github.com/angular-eslint/angular-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/use-lifecycle-interface.md) rule to enforce the use of the interfaces.

Comment: To add a bit about their advantages.... 1) it makes it clear at the start of the class what lifecycle hooks are to be used (this isn't always instantly clear if a class has a lot of methods), 2) Typescript will warn you if you have not implemented the correct method (e.g. forgotten to implement, misspelled a function name or someone has removed it accidentally later on)

Comment: Thanks @Nick, I added the advantages to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

In typescript, you don't need to implement explicitely an interface to implement it.

Take a look at the following piece of code :

```
export interface BaseModel {

   int myNumber;

}

export class SomeModel {

    int myNumber;

}
```

The following is perfectly correct :

```
private myFunction(myModel: BaseModel) {
    // Do smthg
}

let johnDoe = new SomeModel();
myFunction(johnDoe);
```

Perfectly legit because type checking is not based on what class is implementing, but because all the properties of BaseModel are contained into SomeModel.

> This is sometimes called “duck typing” or “structural subtyping”

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html